# Should you remove the assignment of event to a control

Tags: .net, winforms

While talking to my boss who seems to be extremely knowledgeable about .NET today, he had said that I should get in the habit of deleting the assignment of an event to a control in the designer.

I don't remember his exact explanation, but I recall something along the lines of the the event not being contained within the same thread and it actually doesn't fully get cleaned up by garbage collection? It was over a phone discussion and my headset sucks, couldn't hear him well to recall exactly what he said

I was just hoping someone could elaborate, or point me in a direction to read about it further?

Thanks!

For what it's worth, we're using .NET 3.5

Comment: The way I have understood and the rule of thumb that I use, is that if you add the event in the designer you are ok and do not have to remove it. But on the other hand if you manually add it in the code behind you will need to remove it yourself to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: @MarkHall Oh is that what it was? He had talked about it to leading memory leaks, which I thought sounded weird since by default VS will create the code in the designer for you.

Guess he must have been talking about if I manually assigned it in the code, as you said.

Comment: Not a hundred percent sure of what he was talking about(I wasn't there :) ), but those are the guidelines that I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a simple rule for this.  Explicitly unsubscribing an event is only required when the event source object out-lives the event subscriber object.

That's almost never the case in a Winforms app since the form object and the components and controls it contains die at the same time.  The form has a reference to the controls through the Controls collection.  A control can have a reference to the form through its event's delegate object which could keep the form object alive.  Your boss' worry.  The garbage collector however has no trouble with circular references like this, it collects the form object at the same time as the control and event delegate objects.

There are a few select cases where the event source object *does* outlive the subscriber object.  The case for the Application.Idle event and the SystemEvents events.  Notable about these events is that they are *static* and thus keep their subscribing object reference for the life of the program, the GC cannot help.  Explicitly unsubscribing these events is required when closing the form doesn't otherwise terminate the app.

If you have any doubt about your own code then use a memory profiler to verify your assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Exactly what I was hoping for.